# Right way to fetch parent table with it's child tables

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I have one to many relationship on parent and child tables. And trying to fetch parent table with it's child tables as `json`.

I tried something like below.

```
if (request.method == "GET"):   

    parents = Parent.objects.all()
    datas = []
    childTables = []
    for parent in parents:

        #fetching parent first and creating DICT for json
        #also creating an array for the child tables

        parentDict = {
            "id": parent.id,
            "project_name": parent.project_name,
            childTables: childTables,
        }

        #then fetching child tables NO problem at this part as well.
        childs = parent.child_set.filter(parent_id=parent)
        for child in childs:
            #creating a DICT FOR THE json.
            childDict = {
                "id":child.id,
                "ad_kind":child.ad_kind,
                "parent_id":child.parent_id,
            }

            #i am trying to append project's childs into ParentDict 
            #but still it's appending all childs into every ParentDict...
            #not just its parent's childs.
            parentDict["childTables"].append(childDict)


        #at last append all parent table inside an array and send it as JSON. 
        datas.append(parentDict)

    return JsonResponse(datas, safe=False)
```

the problem starts when I try to append `child tables` inside it's `parent` dict. But in above way, I just append all childs into every parent dict...

is there any other simpler way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies at your `childTables` array. You should put it inside the parent loop and if you do that it will renew on each loop. Then you can get the expected results.

```
for parent in parents:

    #childTable array placed in here.
    #to renew on each loop.
    childTable = []

    parentDict = {
        "id": parent.id,
        "project_name": parent.project_name,
        childTables: childTables,
    }

    #... the rest is fine.
```

Answer (score 0):

Python lists are *mutable*, and you are only creating one *"childTables"* list instance **before** the parent loop.  The dictionary key that references **childTables** references the original list, so each addition to the list appends values to that same list.

To fix this, simply create a new list on each parent iteration:

```
for parent in Parent.objects.all():

    parentDict = {
        "id": parent.id,
        "project_name": parent.project_name,
        childTables: [],
    }
```

On a side note, this is not the best way to convert Django querysets into JSON objects.  For that I would recommend using [django rest framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/).

Comment: Why not it is not best way to convert Django querysets int Json objects? Why django-rest-framework way is better?